# ASCII character reading issue: Euro symbol coming empty

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, ascii

How can i read &#128; from xml file to java

gives me an error. I want € to be printed

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/stikkoo/Desktop/product.xml; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 18; The character reference must end with the ';' delimiter.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
```

My XML snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1001">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="&#128;">
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

Comment: you should use unicode  "\\u20AC"

Comment: put some code how you parsing the tree?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, € is not a valid ASCII character.  Real ASCII is a 7 bit character set which predates the invention of the € symbol by 30+ years.

Next, € is not present in LATIN-1 (ISO/IEC 8859-1) either.  If you need € in an 8-bit ISO/IEC 8859 character set, you need to use ISO-8859-15.  The code is `0xA4` or `164` decimal.

In Unicode, the code point for € is `U+20AC`.  That can be written in XML using hexadecimal character entity syntax; `&#x20AC;`.

Note:

- The hexadecimal digits are case insensitive.
- You could also use decimal character entity syntax; `&#8364;`, but I prefer the hexadecimal form because it better aligns with the Unicode code charts.

Alternatively, you can use the XML / HTML named character entity `&euro;` ... assuming that your XML parser understands it.

---

Finally, since you have specified UTF-8 as the encoding for your XML document, you *should* be able to paste a literal € character into the document ... assuming that you are editing it with a UTF-8 aware editor.   (But that has disadvantages too ...)

---

(There are restrictions on the characters you can use in an XML `id`, but the € character is allowed.)

---

For the record, the `&#128;` character entity that you are trying to use in your document actually refers to a non-printing C1 control character.

Comment: `&#x20AC;` (base 16) or `&#8364;` (base 10).

Comment: Yes.  I recommend the hex form because that is preferred notation from the Unicode standards.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Shreya**!

I think you might have the wrong hexadecimal character for your version of xml.
Try `&#x20AC;` or `&#8364;`.
The following link has a huge wall of text describing basically your exact question!

[Link to solve all your problems](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/09/18/euroxml.html)   :)

Good luck with it!

Jesper